# Efficient way to get NonEmpty members

Tags: ssas, mdx

Consider Dimension_A and Dimension_B and Measure_Amt
I require first 100 non-empty members for cross-join between Dimension_A and Dimension_B for Measure_Amt. The following query works but takes a lot of time since these dimensions are large(from million to 20 million)

```
 with set a as subset(Dimension_A.levels(1),0,100)
    set x as SubSet(NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN(a,Dimension_B.levels(1)), 0, 100)
    select [Measures].[Measure_Amt] on 0 ,
    x on 1 
    from MY_CUBE
```

and with where clause,

```
with set a as subset(Dimension_A.levels(1),0,100)
set x as SubSet(NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN(a,Dimension_B.levels(1)), 0, 100)
select [Measures].[Measure_Amt] on 0 ,
x on 1 
from MY_CUBE where Dimension_C.member_C1
```

Fetching first 100 members of a single Dimension is quick, the nonempty function accounts for most of the time.
Since I require only first 100 non-empty members and not the next subset, is there a way to write a better query.

Comment: I ran it against my two big dimensions and it worked really fast. Can you show query against AW base which we can test?

Comment: why do you use `NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN(...)` rather than just `NONEMPTY(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "I require first 100 non-empty members for cross-join between Dimension_A and Dimension_B for Measure_Amt", I assume that you mean want to the top 100 results, where the Measure_Amt is not null for the two cross-joined sets.

If so, I believe this is another way to write your query which may improve performance.

```
WITH 
    SET [X] AS [Dimension_A].LEVELS(1) * [Dimension_B].LEVELS(1)
SELECT
    [Measures].[Measure_Amt] ON 0,
    SUBSET(
        NONEMPTY(
            [X]
            , [Measures].[Measure_Amt]
        )
        , 0
        , 100
    ) ON 1
FROM 
    [MY_CUBE]
WHERE 
    [Dimension_C].[member_C1]
```